# Why MongoDB / MongoHub imports some float values as Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY?

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, mongoimport, mongohub, nosql

I did an exports of a collection (from my localhost) with the MongoDB client MongoHub and then imported also with MongoHub to a remote server.

Today I found that 142 values (of 68k) float values are `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` in the remote server.

It happens in different property names, e.g; `byGender.women`

Localhost:

```
"byGender": {
  "women": 10.232445707200000129,
  "men": 43.622531699299997854
},
```

Remote server:

```
"byGender": {
  "women": Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
  "men": 43.622531699299997854
},
```

I checked the export file and data it's correct so the issue should be in the import.

I give as example other values that are converted to Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY:

- 44.202104087999998683
- 19.085516518799998664
- 20.620553158300001684
- 18.124746482399999081
- 1.8338334224999999211

Do you know if there is a reason?

Server is Ubuntu 16.04, Mongo v3.2.7

Answer (score 0):

Solved doing the export and import by command line. It might be a mongoHub bug.

Export:

```
mongoexport --db databaseName --collection collectionName --out fileName.json
```

Import:

```
mongoimport -d databaseName -c collectionName --type json --file fileName.json
```